# Edición no visible

Tags: soporte, interfaz-de-usuario, línea-de-tiempo

Tenía la página abierta, con la pestaña `Activas` seleccionada, y me ha aparecido una edición de esta pregunta:

[Mostrar repeticiones de un valor en un array en c](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425921/mostrar-repeticiones-de-un-valor-en-un-array-en-c)

Coloco aquí la imagen de lo que veo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Indica claramente `modificada hace 22 min`.

Sin embargo, al entrar en la pregunta en cuestión, me aparece esto otro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También se ve claramente que dice `editada hace 2 días`

Si hago *click* en la línea de tiempo, tampoco aparece nada en los últimos minutos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- ¿ Cual ha sido y donde está esa `modificación hace 22 min` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay una respuesta eliminada. El enlace 'hoy' señala a `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/425921/mostrar-repeticiones-de-un-valor-en-un-array-en-c/426514` y `426514` es el numero de la respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesitas [10,000 reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) para ver publicaciones eliminadas.

Comment: Bueno, pues habrá que esperar algunos años hasta tener esos `10.000` :-(